# Bootstrap Modal Not Correctly Loading Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a test modal to be eventually used in a contact directory. When clicking on a button, a variable (email address) will be passed to the sub GetSpecificAccount in the AccountsDB object. In the test modal, I've hard coded the email address to be passed to make it easier; however, when I click on the button, the content doesn't load.

```
    <center><asp:Button ID="btnTestButton" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateModal" OnClientClick="ShowModal(); return false" Text="Test Modal" /></center>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text="Name Placeholder" /></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><b>Name:  </b>&nbsp<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName2" Text="Name Placeholder" /></p>
        <p><b>Email: </b>&nbsp<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEmail" Text="Email Placeholder" /></p>
        <p><b>Info:  </b>&nbsp<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblInfo" Text="Info Placeholder" /></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" cssclass="btn btn-primary" URL="">Contact</asp:HyperLink>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<script>
    function ShowModal() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    }
</script>

Protected Sub UpdateModal()
    AccountsDB.GetSpecificAccount("test@test.com")
    lblName.Text = AccountsDB.AccountsDataset.Tables("Accounts").Rows(0).Item("FirstName").ToString
    lblEmail.Text = AccountsDB.AccountsDataset.Tables("Accounts").Rows(0).Item("email").ToString
    lblName2.Text = AccountsDB.AccountsDataset.Tables("Accounts").Rows(0).Item("FirstName").ToString & " " & AccountsDB.AccountsDataset.Tables("Accounts").Rows(0).Item("LastName").ToString
    lblInfo.Text = "Test info hardcode"
End Sub
```

Comment: You are doing a full PostBack. If you want to partially refresh your page (on Button click only update modal div) then you need to implement some kind of ajax: For example an `UpdatePanel`.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Button, data dont sended on server (because 'return false;').

Comment: When I take out the "return false," the modal loads data correctly, but closes automatically within seconds

Comment: because after javaScript function completed, your page is reloaded. You need to include your div in updatePanel, take out OnClientClick on button. On server side in Sub UpdateModal() call js function like this:   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(String), "ShowPanel", "ShowModal();", True)

Comment: How do you implement an updatepanel, I haven't used one in the past

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                         <ContentTemplate><div id='MyModal'/>..   </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: I suspect I'm having some issues with the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript line. I'm getting a syntax error in Visual Studio stating that System.Web.UI.IScriptManager is not accesible in this context because it is "friend." I've also inserted a <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" /> control into the aspx file

Comment: Now the page just seems to reload without showing the modal, any suggestions @bogdanovmax ?